# Oracle SQL query to get all agents reporting directy or indirectly to a manager

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

I have a employee hierarchy table in the below format

```
EMPLOYEE_NO  TEAM_ROLE          MANAGER_EMP_NO
10001        Functional_Manager 
123          Center_Manager     10001
10           Team_Manager       123
11           Team_Manager       123
12           Team_Manager       123
1            Agent              10
2            Agent              10
5            Agent              11
6            Agent              11
7            Agent              11
8            Agent              12
456          Center_Manager     10001
15           Team_Manager       456
9            Agent              15
```

I want all agents reporting directly or indirectly to a manager (Team_Manager or Center_Manager or Functional_Manager)

I want to generate the below result with the above data:-

```
 EMPLOYEE_NO            TEAM_ROLE            AGENT_EMP_NO
 10001                  Functional_Manager   1
 10001                  Functional_Manager   2
 10001                  Functional_Manager   5
 10001                  Functional_Manager   6
 10001                  Functional_Manager   7
 10001                  Functional_Manager   8
 10001                  Functional_Manager   9
 123                    Center_Manager       1
 123                    Center_Manager       2
 123                    Center_Manager       5
 123                    Center_Manager       6
 123                    Center_Manager       7
 123                    Center_Manager       8
 10                     Team_Manager         1
 10                     Team_Manager         2
 11                     Team_Manager         5
 11                     Team_Manager         6
 11                     Team_Manager         7
 12                     Team_Manager         8
 1                      Agent                1
 2                      Agent                2
 5                      Agent                5
 6                      Agent                6
 7                      Agent                7
 8                      Agent                8
 9                      Agent                9
```

I guess this can be done with the help of **connect by** queries, but I am not quite sure exactly how to do it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the requirement in proper format. Or provide the snap shot of your requirements

Comment: @JimMacaulay Sorry for the messy formatting. Edited with proper format now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find query below

```
with your_data as ( 
select 10001 employee_no,'Functional_Manager' team_role, null manager_emp_no from dual union 
select 123,'Center_Manager',10001 from dual union 
select 10,'Team_Manager',123 from dual union 
select 11,'Team_Manager',123 from dual union 
select 12,'Team_Manager',123 from dual union 
select 1,'Agent',10 from dual union 
select 2,'Agent',10 from dual union 
select 5,'Agent',11 from dual union  
select 6,'Agent',11 from dual union 
select 7,'Agent',11 from dual union 
select 8,'Agent',12 from dual union 
select 456,'Center_Manager',10001 from dual union 
select 15,'Team_Manager',456 from dual union 
select 9,'Agent',15 from dual), 
t1 as (SELECT  manager_emp_no,  team_role,  employee_no as agent_emp_no, sys_connect_by_path( manager_emp_no, ',' ) path 
FROM your_data 
start with manager_emp_no is null 
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_no = manager_emp_no), 
t2 as (select 
      t1.manager_emp_no,
      t1.team_role,
      t1.agent_emp_no,
      regexp_substr(t1.path, '[^,]+', 1, commas.column_value)  as connect_by
    from
      t1,
      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t1.path, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) commas) 
SELECT distinct connect_by_root agent_emp_no as manager_emp_no ,connect_by_root team_role as team_role,agent_emp_no
FROM t2
where agent_emp_no in (select employee_no from your_data where team_role = 'Agent')
CONNECT BY PRIOR agent_emp_no = connect_by
order by manager_emp_no desc nulls first, agent_emp_no asc
```

Output

```
"MANAGER_EMP_NO"    "TEAM_ROLE" "AGENT_EMP_NO"
10001   "Functional_Manager"    1
10001   "Functional_Manager"    2
10001   "Functional_Manager"    5
10001   "Functional_Manager"    6
10001   "Functional_Manager"    7
10001   "Functional_Manager"    8
10001   "Functional_Manager"    9
456 "Center_Manager"    9
123 "Center_Manager"    1
123 "Center_Manager"    2
123 "Center_Manager"    5
123 "Center_Manager"    6
123 "Center_Manager"    7
123 "Center_Manager"    8
15  "Team_Manager"  9
12  "Team_Manager"  8
11  "Team_Manager"  5
11  "Team_Manager"  6
11  "Team_Manager"  7
10  "Team_Manager"  1
10  "Team_Manager"  2
9   "Agent" 9
8   "Agent" 8
7   "Agent" 7
6   "Agent" 6
5   "Agent" 5
2   "Agent" 2
1   "Agent" 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm!!! Although I am sorry I have now done some modification in the desired results...Let me know how this can be achieved...

Your query seems quite complex ....so was just wondering if the same can be achieved in a simpler way...Just a thought though!!

Comment: @Soumya7oct I updated the query to match your revised output. I dont know any simpler way to do this sorry :D

Comment: Please dont forget to mark the answer as correct :-)